# Kitematic or other GUI based options to connect to a remote docker host

Tags: user-interface, docker, coreos

I have installed CoreOS on a laptop to use it as a Docker host. I really like Kitematic on my mac to create and manager containers. I dont see an option to connect to the remote docker on CoreOS using Kitematic. Are there other tools I can use to connect to a remote docker host and use GUI rather than command line to manager it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also like Kitematic a lot! As an alternative in CoreOS, you can try [docker-ui](https://github.com/kevana/ui-for-docker), and it's evolution [portainer](https://github.com/portainer/portainer).

They are both docker containers that can help you find / run docker images and inspect docker volumes / network / container stats.

You can also launch new containers directly through the web UI. More information on [this good review of the portainer's possibilities](https://media-glass.es/portainer-the-ui-for-docker-d067f6335f23#.ih1k5ni5p)

[Rancher UI](https://github.com/rancher/ui) from Rancher Labs maybe also be worth looking at. It is more designed as a docker orchestration tool (when you operate a docker swarm cluster for instance).

Comment: Ok @HemalShah, let me know if you find other useful tools that would be worth listing in the answer so that it can be shared with others.